# DataGridView does not show when DataSource is set

Tags: c#, datagridview

I used LINQ to load a float array from DB. Even though I succeeded in loading the array, I cannot make a DataGridView to show that array.

Here is my code

```
float[] balances = client.LoadBalance(id); 
// LoadBalance() give me an array of floats of customer who has the specified id
dataBalance.DataSource = balances;
```

I tried the following, yet they are not helping

```
dataBalance.Refresh();
dataBalance.Parent.Refresh();
```

and

```
dataBalance.DataSource = null;
dataBalance.DataSource = balances;
```

I added a breakpoint after `float[] balances = client.LoadBalance(id);` and I am sure that the `LoadBalance(id)` works.
Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution, just create a Class for your `balances`

Let say, `BalanceClass`

```
public class BalanceClass
{
    public float balances { get; set; }
}
```

then

```
float[] balances = client.LoadBalance(id);
List<BalanceClass> bal = new List<BalanceClass>();
foreach (var item in balances)
   bal.Add(new BalanceClass() { balances = item});
ataGridView2.DataSource = bal.ToList();
```

Comment: It works! Can you please enlighten me why?
Moreover, you do not need `bal.ToList()` since `bal` is a List, I deleted the `ToList()` and it stills works

Comment: heres a good explanation about [.ToList()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774099/tolist-does-it-create-a-new-list)

Comment: Thank you, I meant that why creating a new class put these values to my DB, while leaving them as a `List<int>` does not work?

Answer (score 1):

You need dataBalance.DataBind(); after dataBalance.DataSource = balances;

Comment: This is only for web (ASP.NET), in winform, we don't have this method and it's not neccessary at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
     dataGridView1.DataSource = 
            (LoadBalance(id) ?? new float[0])
                .Select(x => new { Number = x })
                .ToList();
```