# Strange, IEnumerable.ToList() creates entirely new objects

Tags: c#, list, .net-4.0, ienumerable

I know IEnumerable.ToList() is supposed to create a new List, but with the items pointing to the same original items in the IEnumerable, as discussed at [ToList()-- Does it Create a New List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774099/tolist-does-it-create-a-new-list)

However, I'm getting some strange behavior with my code using VS 2012; WPF; and .NET 4.0. It started when IEnumerable.SequenceEquals() seemed not to work as I expected. I dug around with my QuickWatch dialog, and, unbelievably, the following statement evaluates to false:

```
this.Items.First () == this.Items.ToList ()[ 0 ]
```

I even tried:

```
this.Items.ToList ().IndexOf(this.Items.First ())
```

which evaluated to -1.

`Items` is declared as a property on a WPF custom control, like so:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register (
        "Items", 
        typeof ( IEnumerable<UserLayoutType> ), 
        typeof ( UserLayoutSelectorControl ),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata ( null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, UserLayoutSelectorControl.PropertyChanged ) );


public IEnumerable<UserLayoutType> Items
{
    get
    {
        return ( IEnumerable<UserLayoutType> ) this.GetValue ( UserLayoutSelectorControl.ItemsProperty );
    }
    set
    {    
        this.SetValue ( UserLayoutSelectorControl.ItemsProperty, value );                
    }
}
```

UserLayoutType is simply a class generated by the XSD tool, with the following declaration:

```
// 
// This source code was auto-generated by xsd, Version=4.0.30319.17929.
// 
namespace MyAssays.UserLayoutCore.UserLayoutUtility {
    using System.Xml.Serialization;


    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.17929")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("UserLayout", Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
    public partial class UserLayoutType {
```

This are the methods on a factory class that create the UserLayoutType Items in the first place:

```
public static IEnumerable<UserLayoutType> CreateFromFolder ( string folderPath )
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(folderPath))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("folderPath", "Folder path must not be null");

        var userLayoutXmlFilePaths = Directory.GetFiles ( folderPath ).Where ( filePath => filePath.EndsWith ( ".UserLayout.xml", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase ) );
        return userLayoutXmlFilePaths.Select(filePath => UserLayoutFactory.CreateFromFile(filePath));
    }

    public static UserLayoutType CreateFromFile ( string filePath )
    {
        using ( var stream = new StreamReader ( filePath ) )
        {
            return ( UserLayoutType ) new XmlSerializer ( typeof ( UserLayoutType ) ).Deserialize ( stream );
        }
    }
```

Anybody have any idea what is happening? See image below:
[image]

Comment: hi, please try the .Equals method, ie.
this.Items.First().equals(this.Items.ToList ()[ 0 ])

Comment: What is items declared to be? I think it's best to try to create a short simple piece of code that shows the issues that you're talking about. Then post the code in your question. Besides that you need to learn the difference between == and .Equals()

Comment: What is the runtime type of `this.Items`? There's no override on `Equals` or `==`?

Comment: Is it possible that `UserLayoutType` is a struct?

Comment: No, there is no override on Equals

Comment: @ user814064: I know the difference between Equals and ==. ToList is supposed to return items that refer to the same original items. I am checking for reference equality, not value quality. UserLayoutType is a class, not a structure, and so == should return true if the references point to the same object

Comment: What does `this.Items.GetType()` return?

Comment: When you say: var left = this.Items.First ();
var right = this.Items.ToList ()[ 0 ]; // Do left and right look like they are same when you stop in the Visual Studio debugger>?

Comment: @ user814064: At the point I'm getting these issues, Items.GetType().Name returns "WhereSelectArrayIterator`2". And, yes, this.Items.First () seems to be equal to this.Items.ToList ()[ 0 ] when I step through.

Comment: @Alex: I have added the start of the declaration for the UserLayoutType to the main question

Comment: Could it be that your `Items` property is creating new objects each time it is called. What does the following evaluate to? `var left = this.Items.First(); var right = this.Items.First(); var result = left == right;`

Comment: @Timothy Walters: Interesting, result = left == right returns false

Comment: Perhaps that `WhereSelectArrayIterator` is doing something like `RealItems.Select(t => new SneakyWrapper(t))`

Comment: In the property getter is it possible to replace the cast to IEnumerable<UserLayoutType> into use of "as"? If so, does that make a difference?

Comment: @TimothyWalters: Your comment got me thinking about the factory method that generates the UserLayoutType items in the first place. I changed the last line in IEnumerable<UserLayoutType> CreateFromFolder(...) to return a list (using .ToList()) instead of an IEnumerable (since a List IS an IEnumerable, the interface does not change). However, with this change, result is now true. It seems the control was using the iterator on the XML files to re-generate the Items property on every get

Comment: And so when I use a List instead of a true IEnumerable as the initial value for the property, everything just works. This indicates something significant; the answers to the question at (stackoverflow.com/questions/2774099/…) will therefore need to be updated. In case where the IEnumerable is a true IEnumerable (i.e. not just a collection packaged an as enumerable), ToList() may NOT return the same object references as in the IEnumerable. It will return a new List of objects which may not be the same or even Equal to the objects yielded by the IEnumerable when it is enumerated again

Comment: @prmph You should post that as an answer to your own question, you can accept your own answer to a question after 2 days from when you first asked has passed. It may help a future visitor.

Answer (score 7):

The main, probable, cause for why you're seeing new objects from this is that the `IEnumerable<T>` is wrapping a generator, and not a materialized collection.

Here's a simple [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) program to demonstrate:

```
void Main()
{
    IEnumerable<string> collection =
        from index in Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
        select "Index=" + index;

    var list1 = collection.ToList();
    var list2 = collection.ToList();

    ReferenceEquals(list1[0], list2[0]).Dump();
}
```

This will print `False`.

It will do this because the act of enumerating over the collection (`.ToList()` in this case) will execute the deferred LINQ query, and since we're enumerating the collection twice, we execute it twice, producing different instances with the same values.