# How to update values in collection type object

Tags: c#

I created a list object of class and after that m updating its value its value not updating please help me here is my code

```
public class LocationData
{
    public int LocId { get; set; }
    public string LocatinName { get; set; }
    public int ControlCount { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> KeyType { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> Financial_Reporting { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> FraudRisk { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> FinancialControl { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> ELC { get; set; }
}

 var locList = location.Select(a =>
               new LocationData { LocatinName = a.Location, LocId = a.LocID });
```

after that I'm trying to update the value in this:

```
locList.Where(a => a.LocId == 7).ToList()
       .ForEach(b => b.ControlCount = b.ControlCount + 1);
```

but nothing is updated i also try this but not updated

```
(from loc in locList select loc).ToList().ForEach((loc) =>
{
   loc.ControlCount = loc.ControlCount + 1;
});
```

Comment: Just loop through the list and update each item's attributes.

Comment: yes Grant Winney i m completely sure about values

Comment: I suspect the issue is with your call to [ToList](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2774099/21727)

Comment: Try this locList.FindAll(a => a.LocId == 7).ToList().ForEach(b => b.ControlCount = b.ControlCount + 1);

Comment: HI  mbeckish i try this foreach loop but not updated   foreach (LocationData loc in locList)
               {
                   if (loc.LocId == item.TopLoc)
                   {
                       loc.ControlCount = 1;
                   }
               }

Comment: Did you follow @MarcinJuraszek's advice and call ToList() when declaring lacList?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because you don't actually take any object materialized when `lacList` is declared. It's just a query definition (because LINQ execution is defered), so every time you use it new `LocationDate` items are created.

Call `ToList()` when declaring `lacList` and it will work:

```
var locList= location.Select(a => new LocationData { LocatinName = a.Location, LocId = a.LocID }).ToList();
```

And to be honest, I don't see why you're using `List<T>.ForEach` method instead od `foreach` loop. You have to materialize new `List<T>` to call that method with `Where` filter set on source collection. You wouldn't have to do that when using `foreach`:

```
foreach(var item in locList.Where(a => a.LocID == 7))
{
    item.ControlCount += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do like this in one line

```
locList.Where(o => o.LocID == 7).Select(aa => aa.ControlCount += 1).ToList();
```