# Does tasks.ToList() create a list containing newly copied tasks or the list refers to the same tasks?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

Assume we have an array of tasks (called 'tasks') and then convert it to a list (called 'temp') by saying:

```
var temp = tasks.ToList();
```

What happens to those running tasks to which the array elements point? Do we have two sets of tasks running separately (one in the 'tasks' and the other in 'temp')? Or they point to the same tasks?

The following code (taken from the book Exam Ref 70-483 ) is relevant to what I'm saying (the last three lines):

```
Task<int>[] tasks = new Task<int>[3];

tasks[0] = Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(2000); return 1; });
tasks[1] = Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(1000); return 2; });
tasks[2] = Task.Run(() => { Thread.Sleep(3000); return 3; });

while (tasks.Length > 0) {
    int i = Task.WaitAny(tasks);
    Task<int> completedTask = tasks[i];

    Console.WriteLine(completedTask.Result);

    var temp = tasks.ToList();
    temp.RemoveAt(i);
    tasks = temp.ToArray();
}
```

UPDATE: I know the purpose of the last three lines but do not know why it work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What happens [when we call ToList on a sequence of tasks]? Do we have two sets of tasks running separately? Or they point to the same tasks?

This is actually a good question, and it depends on the source sequence on which you call `ToList`. If `temp` is a collection of running tasks (as in your case), then `ToList` simply creates a copy of their references, meaning your new list would point to the same set of tasks.

However, if `temp` constitutes a sequence of tasks that have yet to be instantiated (due to deferred execution), then you would get a *new* set of tasks each time you call `ToList`. Here is a simple example (using `ToArray`, which has the same effect as `ToList`):

```
int count = 0;

var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(_ => 
    Task.Run(() => Interlocked.Increment(ref count)));

// tasks = tasks.ToArray();   // deferred vs. eager execution

Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

Console.WriteLine(count);
```

If you run the code above, the final result will be `20`, meaning that two batches of tasks were run (one for each `ToArray` call). However, if you uncomment the line that enables eager execution, the final result will become `10`, indicating that the subsequent `ToArray` calls only copy the references, rather than spawn new tasks.

Answer (score 3):

`ToList` creates a new list containing the IEnumerable's items. It does *not* create a deep copy of those items, it only copies the references. So there is only a **single** set of tasks.

Those lines are probably there so the developer could use `RemoveAt` to easily remove an item using an index (the index returned from `Task.WaitAny`)

Comment: MSDN says:"List<T>.ToArray() Copies the elements of the ArrayList to a new array" (which pertains to the last line of code).

Comment: It means it copies the references. It doesn't create new items, tasks in this case. Both list and array contain the same actual tasks.

Comment: I found a very relevant QA which explain it very well :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774099/tolist-does-it-create-a-new-list

Comment: Plesae put your comment into your answer as it is the real answer.