# Is a Linq-Query called toList() generating copies of the contained elements?

Tags: c#, linq

I encountered a (for me) strange behaviour. Here is the code:

```
var objects = from i in items
              //some calculations
              select something;

// other calculations

objects.ToList().ForEach(x => {
    //some calculations
    x.Property = "some text"
});

return objects;
```

First I generate a `IEnumerable`, it is a query to the db, I skipped the details.
Then I have to do other calculations and at the end I iterate over my objects to set a further parameter. Running this code, once the `IEnumerable` objects is returned, their `Property` is not set.

Otherwise if I move the `ToList()` in the Linq expression as followed, the `Property` is set:

```
var objects = (from i in items
              //some calculations
              select something).ToList();

// other calculations

objects.ForEach(x => {
    //some calculations
    x.Property = "some text"
});

return objects;
```

As far I know, the objects are not copied, but referenced...right?
What does behind the apparently codes happen? What is the difference?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ToList()-- Does it Create a New List?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774099/tolist-does-it-create-a-new-list)

Comment: When you do `objects.ToList()` the query get executed. Then you return `objects`. Let's say that someone then iterate over that returned object: in this case the query will be executed again (so new objects will be created)

Comment: `var objects` without `ToList` is just a query, so the definition not the execution. If you materialize it, for example with `ToList` or `forach` it is executed. So by appending `ToList` the database gets queried and an in-memory list is filled. `List.ForEach` will enumerate them and you modify the property. In the first approach this list is thrown away immediately because it is not stored in a variable. The second version is correct.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Could you please explain the "this list is thrown away immediately because it is not stored in a variable"? Even though it is not materialized on the variable definition, shouldn't it be once the ToList or ForEach gets executed, storing the result on the objects variable?

Comment: @NahuelIanni: no, the `objects` variable is still just the db-query. The list is not stored anywhere. Another, probably better, approach is to assign the text to the property in the query itself. Then you don't need to loop the list afterwards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember that a Linq query is just a query - it is saying "if I ask for this data, here's what I want_.  It does not hold any data but waits until you ask_ for the results (via `foreach`, `ToList`, `ToArray`, etc.)

The difference is you're not *capturing* the list returned by `ToList` in the first example.  It's used by the `ForEach` call but the `objects` variable still holds a reference to the original *query*.  When you ask for it again - it fetches the data again.  When it fetches the data again, new objects are created.

So in that respect - yes `ToList()` creates a new list.  It does not *modify* the object that it's called on to turn it into a list.

In your second example the `objects` variable holds a reference to the *list* generated from the query via `ToList()`, so when you modify them and return `objects` you're returning the same list.

Comment: @Taemyr I think you're the one not understanding. What DStanley and I wrote in our answers is exactly what's happening.

Comment: @DStanley The first edit makes a significant improvement.  Although I would prefer an answer that makes it explicit that the new items are created by the select.

Answer (score 0):

In your first code sample the `objects.ToList()` is in fact creating a new object of type `List` you're working on with your `ForEach`. After the `ForEach` is done you're still just returning your `IEnumerable` and the list you actually wanted to return will be gone.

By assigning the LINQ query with a `ToList()` to the `object` variable, you're using the newly created list in your `ForEach`.

Comment: I think you miss the point.  Its the changes to the objects in the list that he is missing.

Comment: Exactly, because he is returning the `IEnumerable` and not storing the resulting list of the `ToList()` call in his first sample.

Comment: @Taemyr The key to this is that the `IEnumerable` is likely a `IQueryable` which means the underlying data are not objects that can be changed, but data that will be queried from the DB on each iteration.

Comment: @juharr Agreed, or the select creates new objects from some other mechanism.  But this answer makes no indication that the items are created during execution of the select.