# Using Linq to filter an array with bool properties true in to another array

Tags: c#, linq

I have an array of type `Brick` with each `brick` having an `isBroken` `bool` property. How can I use `Linq` to filter all bricks with `isBroken = true` into a new array?

Comment: Have you tried this? : `BrickList.Where(x=> x.isBroken).ToList();`

Comment: @un-lucky that would be `.ToArray()` but yes you're right :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Where` to filter the list of bricks and `ToArray` to materialize the result into a new array.

```
var result = MyBricksArray.Where(x => x.isBroken).ToArray();
```

Comment: This will indeed create a new array, but the reference to the objects in the the array would stay the same. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774099/tolist-does-it-create-a-new-list

Answer (score 0):

I hope this [example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/e4WwXH) will explain things more clearly, Let the definition of your class will be like the following:

```
public class Brick
{
  public string Name;
  public bool isBroken ;
}
```

And the Array of it's objects is defined like this:

```
Brick[] BrickArray =new Brick[]{
                    new Brick(){Name="A",isBroken=true},
                    new Brick(){Name="B",isBroken=true},
                    new Brick(){Name="C",isBroken=false}};
```

Then you can use the `.Where` to filter the collection like the following:

```
var selectedBriks = BrickArray.Where(x=>x.isBroken).ToList();
```

Now the `selectedBriks` will contains the items with name `A` and `B`

Answer (score -1):

You can use the select method for this :

```
var theNewList = Brick.Where(b => b.isBroken).Select(b => new Brick
{
    //Populate new object
}).ToList() / .ToArray();
```

Note that Select is used and not where to project the List into a new one.

Also, the .ToList()/ToArray() is to add the array to memory, you may not need it, .Select() return an IEnumerable.
It is possible to use Brik.Where(..).ToList(); as this would create a new List but the reference to the object inside the list would be the same, so again it  depands on your need.
And .Select() require `using System.Linq;`

Comment: Well, to illustrate and add to your answer, that if you want your Bricks to be copy of your initial bricks (in this case)  and not the orignal Brick you have to instanciate new one, it seemed important to me because that's a big difference between instanciating a new list and create a list of new objects