# ASP.NET Core 2.2 Entity Framework: Get subset of data without altering context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-2.2

I am trying to return a list of objects but only include a subset of one property of that object.

**Controller**

```
[ServiceFilter(typeof(LogUserActivity))]
public class CabinsController : Controller
{
    private readonly IBaseRepository _repo;

    public CabinsController(IBaseRepository repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }

    public IActionResult GetCabins()
    {
        return Ok(_repo.GetCabins());

        // upon completing the action, the LogUserActivity 
        // filter saves changes to the database.
    }
}
```

**Repository**

```
public List<Cabin> GetCabins() 
{
    // retrieve list of all cabins
    var cabins = _context.Cabins.ToList();

    // only show current occupants of the cabins
    foreach (var cabin in cabins) {
        cabin.occupants = 
            cabin.occupants.Where(o => 
                o.StartDate <= DateTime.UtcNow && 
                o.EndDate >= DateTime.UtcNow).ToList();
    }

    return cabins;
}
```

However, this is altering `_context` and the database it's connected to. It's deleting all `occupants` that are not current.

How can I retrieve a subset of the object's property without altering the datasource?

Comment: Don't use entity models if you're going to be modifying them. Use a DTO that is completely distinct from the entities.

Comment: Your requirement is not clear! Would tell me please which filtered data are you expecting from `GetCabins()` method and why are you using `foreach` in `GetCabins()`

Comment: @DavidG I do have DTOs. So, what you're saying is that I should alter the data after it's converted to the DTO?

Comment: @DavidG your suggestion worked swimmingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use .toList() on the cabins object which will create a copy for use in the loop:

```
 foreach (var cabin in cabins.toList()) {
```

See [ToList()-- Does it Create a New List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774099/tolist-does-it-create-a-new-list) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

After assigning

```
var cabins = _context.Cabins.ToList();
```

you assign new occupants in _context data object. And later, if you write

```
_context.SaveChanges();
```

it saves DB. Try this one

```
public List<Cabin> GetCabins() 
{
    // retrieve list of all cabins
    var cabins = _context.Cabins.ToList();
    List<Cabins> cabintemp= new List<Cabins>();

    // only show current occupants of the cabins
    cabintemp.occupants=cabins.occupants.Where(o => 
                o.StartDate <= DateTime.UtcNow && 
                o.EndDate >= DateTime.UtcNow)

    }

    return cabintemp;
}
```

Use cabintemp.