# Changing increment variables causes for loop to go over limit

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, for-loop, asp.net-3.5

In my loop I am trying to remove items from a list that have a certain name. I can't do this with a for-each, so I tried a regular for-loop. It seems the for loop is not working as expected. It always goes over the limit. I had to put an if-then to break out of the loop (very ugly solution). I'm trying to find the correct way to accomplish this.

```
Dim canShowNextTable As Boolean = False
    Dim allTablesInTab As List(Of Control) = ctrlFinder.GetTypeOfControls("Table", parentForm.Controls)
    Dim totalTables As Integer = allTablesInTab.Count - 1
    For i As Integer = 0 To totalTables
        If allTablesInTab.Item(i).ID = "CustomerTable" Or _
            allTablesInTab.Item(i).ID = "PMTable" Or _
            allTablesInTab.Item(i).ID = "TableAListClrnCheck" Or _
            allTablesInTab.Item(i).ID = "TableBListClrnCheck" Or _
            allTablesInTab.Item(i).ID = "TableCListClrnCheck" Or _
            allTablesInTab.Item(i).ID = "TableDListClrnCheck" Or _
            allTablesInTab.Item(i).ID = "TableSignature" Then       '' If the ID is one of these remove it from list
            allTablesInTab.Remove(allTablesInTab.Item(i))
            totalTables = totalTables - 1                           '' Decrement number of tables to loop through
            i = -1                                                  '' Reset counter to prevent going over or premature stopping
        End If
        If i = 3 AndAlso totalTables = 3 Then                       '' Since loop continuously goes over limit, use if-then to exit for-loop
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to traverse your loop in reverse because once you remove an item the total count has changed and is no longer correct. Looping in reverse avoids this issue.

```
For i As Integer = totalTables To 0 Step -1
```

Also, instead of `allTablesInTab.Remove(allTablesInTab.Item(i))` you can use:

```
allTablesInTab.RemoveAt(i)
```

Work through this logic on paper or the debugger to properly grasp the concept of what's happening. You might also find this related question useful. It's in C# but the concepts are the same: [How to remove elements from a generic list while iterating around it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582285/)