# Is it safe to remove an entry from a Hashtable while iterating?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

In other words, is this safe?

```
Hashtable myDict = ... //fill with some data

foreach (DictionaryEntry pair in myDict)
{
   if (someCondition)
       myDict.Remove(pair.Key);
}
```

It doesnt seem to have any side effects in my application so far.

edit: i have to mention that in my specific case, this dictionary contains only 1 entry.

edit2: sorry, the datatype is a Hashtable not a Dictionary.

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365725/delete-item-from-dictionary-while-iterating-over-it

Comment: have you tried running a test sample like that?  It will throw an error.  Also a `DictionaryEntry` is the wrong type

Comment: I am sorry, I gave the wrong datatype. it is not a dictionary but a Hashtable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No it is not safe, the contract of `IEnumerator` [specifies that `MoveNext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.movenext.aspx) should throw an exception if the underlying collection was modified after the enumerator was created.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not safe. with every removed entry it will reduce index no and will move to next element with increasing current index no, so it will create problem there.

Answer (score 0):

@Lee gave you the answer.

It would be safe this way:

```
var toDelete = myDict.Where(someCondition).ToArray();
foreach (DictionaryEntry pair in toDelete)
    myDict.Remove(pair.Key);
```