# Is it possible to remove items in a list of a list without loosing the original reference?

Tags: c#, .net

Ok this is a little bit hard to ask, but i will try.
I have a List with objects (Lots), which contains again a list with objects (Wafers).
When i change a value within a wafer it will be changed in both lists! Thats what i want.
But when i want to remove a wafer from the copied list, it should not be removed from the orginal list. So i want to have a new List of wafers in each lot but the references to the wafers should be the same as in the original lot because i want to change values to the wafers and it should change the values in the orginal wafer and copied wafer. Is it possible without deep copy?

I have the following code, to explain it better:

```
    public class Lot
    {
        public string LotName { get; set; }

        public List<Wafer> Wafers { get; set; }
    }

    public class Wafer
    {
        public string WaferName { get; set; }

    }
    [Test]
    public void ListInListTest()
    {
                    //Some Testdata

        List<Lot> lotList = new List<Lot>();
        Lot lot = new Lot();
        lot.LotName = "Lot1";
        lot.Wafers = new List<Wafer>();
        Wafer wafer = new Wafer();
        wafer.WaferName = "Wafer1";
        lot.Wafers.Add(wafer);
        wafer = new Wafer();
        wafer.WaferName = "Wafer2";
        lot.Wafers.Add(wafer);
        wafer = new Wafer();
        wafer.WaferName = "Wafer3";
        lot.Wafers.Add(wafer);
        wafer = new Wafer();
        wafer.WaferName = "Wafer4";
        lot.Wafers.Add(wafer);
        lotList.Add(lot);

        lot = new Lot();
        lot.LotName = "Lot1";
        lot.Wafers = new List<Wafer>();
        wafer = new Wafer();
        wafer.WaferName = "Wafer1";
        lot.Wafers.Add(wafer);
        wafer = new Wafer();
        wafer.WaferName = "Wafer2";
        lot.Wafers.Add(wafer);
        wafer = new Wafer();
        wafer.WaferName = "Wafer3";
        lot.Wafers.Add(wafer);
        wafer = new Wafer();
        wafer.WaferName = "Wafer4";
        lot.Wafers.Add(wafer);
        lotList.Add(lot);

         //Copy the List
        List<Lot> copyList = CopyList(lotList);

        //That works. It removes the lot just in the copyList but not in 
        //the original one
        copyList.RemoveAt(1);

        //This works not like i want. It removes the wafers from the copied list
        //and the original list. I just want, that the list will be changed
        //in the copied list
        copyList[0].Wafers.RemoveAt(0);


    }

    private List<Lot> CopyList(List<Lot> lotList)
    {
        List<Lot> result = new List<Lot>(lotList);

        foreach (Lot lot in result)
        {
            lot.Wafers = new List<Wafer>(lot.Wafers);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

I hope it is not so confusing? And i hope my question is explained good enough.

Comment: you cany try out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582285/how-to-remove-elements-from-a-generic-list-while-iterating-over-it

Comment: You can try to serialize and then deserialize without a deep copy

Comment: Are you sure that it doesn't work? It seems you're doing it right: create a new list of wafers (that's important) which is populated by existing references. Should work.

Comment: No you can't. After all the wafer references aren't copied unless you do deep copy in "CopyList".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can see, there is no out-of-the-box way for you to do what you want. Here is a brief description why:

The `List<Lot>` (far left-hand-side) contains a reference to the `Lot` object, which in turn contains references to both its member variables.

[image]

If you want changes to the `LotName` and constituents of the `Wafers` list to be propagated as you describe, the easiest solution is to share a reference to the `Lot` object between lists:

[image]

Now you can see why it is impossible to modify the items in the list of `Wafers` independently using this solution - you can't get away from the fact that you are using the same object reference!

By sharing a reference you lose the ability to control how differences in behaviour.  To achieve what you want, I think you have to do a deep copy of the `Lot` instances, and you could then manage the propagation of changes through some sort of [Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) pattern.

Comment: Wow, thank you. That make things more clear for me! So when i call "new List<Wafer>()" it will just make a new List for the same lot reference. OK.. than i have to do deep copy. :/

Answer (score 7):

I think I can see what your issue is here. In your `CopyList` you effectively clone the list i.e.

```
lot.Wafers = new List<Wafer>(lot.Wafers);
```

However, the key point to note here is the *reference* to the `Lot` object is still the same - so effectively you are cloning & replacing the `Wafers` property on the original list as well.

When you call

```
copyList.RemoveAt(1);
```

that's fine because you are manipulating a copy of the `Lot` *list*. However, when you call

```
copyList[0].Wafers.RemoveAt(0);
```

you are modifying the `Lot` *instance* which is still being referenced by both lists. To solve the problem you would need to clone the `Lot` object itself to effectively change the reference i.e.

```
List<Lot> result = new List<Lot>(lotList.Count);
foreach (Lot item in lotList)
{
    result.Add(new Lot()
    {
        LotName = item.LotName,
        Wafers = new List<Wafer>(item.Wafers)
    });
}
```

As a result you would lose the automatic update in both lists for the `Lot` object itself but you would still retain it for modifying the individual `Wafer` objects (as the reference for them wouldn't have changed).

So to summarise, what you are effectively asking is:

> How can I keep the same object reference whilst having a different property reference?

The answer to that question is - you can't.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you create the *clone list* by maintaining a reference with the main list. You should use something like:

```
private List<Lot> CopyList(List<Lot> list)
{
   List<Lot> clone = new List<Lot>();

   foreach(Lot l in list)
   {
      List<Wafer> wafers = new List<Wafer>();
      foreach(Wafer w in l.Wafers)
         wafers.Add(w);

      clone.Add(new Lot(){ LotName = l.LotName, Wafers = wafers });
   }

   return clone;
}
```

Comment: No new Wafer's shall be created, it seems. Only the references need to be kept.

Comment: Nope, he doesn't need the reference to _Wafers_, because as you can see he wants to modify the copied list without producing an effect on the main list.

Comment: There's no point in creating new Wafers if it's sufficient to copy the reference.

Comment: I want to have the SAME wafers (same reference). But the list of wafers should be a NEW reference per lot. So the size of the waferlist can be different for example.. So when i remove a wafer from the copied list it should NOT remove it from the original list. But when i change a value of any wafer it should also change the value for the wafer in the corresponding list. What you tried is a deepcopy. But i don't want to have a deep copy, because i want to change values in a wafer once for all the wafers with the same reference. Yes i know..^^ ... a little bit confusing

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes it's possible. However, the CopyList method should look like this

```
private List<Lot> CopyList(List<Lot> lotList)
{
    List<Lot> result = new List<Lot>();

    for (int i = 0; i < lotList.Count; i++)
    {
         Lot lot = new Lot();
         lot.LotName = lotList[i].LotName;
         lot.Wafers = new List<Wafer>(lotList[i].Wafers);
         result.Add(lot);
    }

    return result;
}
```

This will create a new lotlist and add all existing Wafers to it.

Comment: But it doesn't work the way i did. When i remove a wafer from the copied list it removes it also from the original list :(...

Comment: It doesn't work. If you copy/paste it in a console application you'll see the described behaviour.

Comment: @JeffRSon as far as I can see...it's not.

Comment: Okay - yes. The problem is, that the original lists are used. There is a new copy of Wafers, but not a new lotlist. I overlooked that, obviously. Will edit the answer.

Comment: See new version of CopyList

Comment: @JeffRSon this answer is still wrong, it's not possible to have the same reference (`Lot` object) in two lists but have 2 different property (`Wafers`) references. The only solution is to clone the list and keep the objects in sync using some other means (e.g. subject/observer pattern).

Comment: @James: The first line in the for loop creates a new Lot list - so what do you mean? It IS another list and it is added to the copied list (result).

Comment: @JeffRSon your newly proposed solution does as what I have also suggested in my answer - however, you still seem to suggest that what the OP is asking for can be done but using your code - which it can't. When the `Lot` objects are cloned the reference from the original list is lost so updating a `Lot` object in the copy list **will no longer** update the same object in the original list. The OP want's to be able to retain the `Lot` instance across both lists but maintain a separate `Wafers` property per list which can't be done.

Comment: Unless I misread it again, it is the other way around. "So i want to have a new List of wafers in each lot but the references to the wafers should be the same as in the original lot" - so the OP is aware of having different lots and different list of wafers, but the *same* wafers. His question was not about further synchronizing the original and copy of lots, but about removing Wafers without affecting the original. Anyway - the discussion moves away from the actual problem.

Comment: I was focusing more on the "*Is it possible without deep copy?*" to which the answer is no, the `Lot` object needs to be cloned along with the property itself. What the OP is really asking is "*can I have 1 `Lot` object, in 2 separate lists, which reference different `Wafer` lists?*" which isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

You should use two separate variables for the lists, e.g. `ListLotA` and `ListLotB`. If you want to be able to remove a `Wafer` from one list without removing it from another, and at the same time adjust a `Wafer` so that it reflects in both lists, you should copy the Wafers from one list to the other, i.e. by use of a temporary array.

The example code below illustrates this:

```
List<Lot> ListLotA = new List<Lot>();

Wafer w1 = new Wafer() { WaferName = "w1" };
Wafer w2 = new Wafer() { WaferName = "w2" };
Wafer w3 = new Wafer() { WaferName = "w3" };

ListLotA.Wafers.Add(w1);
ListLotA.Wafers.Add(w2);
ListLotA.Wafers.Add(w3);

List<Lot> ListLotB = new List<Lot>();

// At this point adding w1, w2, w3 to the second list is possible, but let's
// assume it's not and you have to copy them from the first list.
Wafer[] wArray = new Wafer[ListLotA.Wafers.Count];
ListLotA.Wafers.CopyTo(wArray);

ListLotB.Wafers.AddRange(wArray);
```

`ListLotA` and `ListLotB` are separate objects, e.g. they have different references, but the list of individual Wafers have the same reference.

```
ListLotB.Wafers[1].WaferName = "New Value";
```

The above line would change the Wafer at index 1 in ListLotB, but it would also effect the same Wafer in ListLotA (despite its index).

```
ListLotA.Wafers.Remove(w2);
```

This would remove Wafer `w2` from ListLotA, but not from ListLotB.