# Remove element from nested list C#

Tags: c#, list

I am trying to work with list of lists.
how do I remove a specific element from the list?
I have the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace TEST3
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            List<List<int>> ar = new List<List<int>> ();
            List<int> innerAr = new List<int> ();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) 
            {
                innerAr.Add (i);
            }
            for (int j = 0; j <= 80; j++) 
            {
                ar.Add (innerAr);
            }
            ar[80].RemoveAt(7);
            ar[80].RemoveAt(2);
            Console.WriteLine (ar[80].Count);
            Console.WriteLine (ar[79].Count);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have?  I'm going to guess you're wondering why the counts for 79 and 80 are the same?

Comment: Here you can find answer. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582285/how-to-remove-elements-from-a-generic-list-while-iterating-over-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int j = 0; j <= 80; j++) 
{
    ar.Add (innerAr);
}
```

All elements in `ar` now contain the same reference to `innerAr`. There is only a single list that you kept adding to `ar`, so when you later change `innerAr` by accessing `ar[80]`, then you also change the `innerAr` of all the other elements (because it’s the same list).

If you want independent list, you need to create one for each `ar` item:

```
List<List<int>> ar = new List<List<int>>();
for (int j = 0; j <= 80; j++) 
{
    List<int> innerAr = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) 
    {
        innerAr.Add(i);
    }
    ar.Add(innerAr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The lists have the **same `Count`** because **is the same list** added multiple times.

If you want just one list to be changed due to `RemoveAt`, you have to create a new one. A simple way to create a new list with same elements is to add `ToList()`.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<List<int>> ar = new List<List<int>>();
    List<int> innerAr = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
    {

        innerAr.Add(i);
    }
    for (int j = 0; j <= 80; j++)
    {
        ar.Add(innerAr.ToList()); // <- here is the change
    }
    ar[80].RemoveAt(7);
    ar[80].RemoveAt(2);
    Console.WriteLine(ar[80].Count); // 7
    Console.WriteLine(ar[79].Count); // 9
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your removal is successful. As Charles hinted your only mistake is that the Object innerAt, is the exact same object that is in each of the 80 lists of List.
since List is an object reference and not a value, you have the same reference in ar[79] and ar[80]

Answer (score 0):

You have parent list

```
 List<List<int>> parent=new List<List<int>>();
```

And your child list

```
List<int> child=new List<int>(){1,2,3};
```

Adding to parent

```
parent.Add(child);
```

child elements 1,2,3

Removing

```
parent[0].removeAt(0)
```

child elements 2,3

Comment: I was going to put above code in .Net fiddle but it is down right now :(