# Get Keys from C# Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

One would imagine this would be a pretty simple task, yet I'm getting a System.InvalidOperationException when I run this code:

```
Dictionary<string, bool> TableExists = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
//... fill the dictionary
foreach(string value in TableExists.Keys){/*Do something*/}
```

It is supposed to iterate through the keys of the dictionary `TableExists`, but I get the Invalid Operation Exception at the `foreach` line. Am I using any Dictionary operations incorrectly? What is the proper way to work through the keys of a C# Dictionary if so?

Edit:

Yes, I was attempting to change some values corresponding to dictionary keys, getting a `Collection was modified` error.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the piece of code you have shown. Something else must be going on.

Comment: What's in the **Do something** could be material to your question.

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: It may have to do with this error then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582285/how-to-remove-elements-from-a-generic-list-while-iterating-over-it . Thanks for the help.

Comment: Don't downvote me bro, don't downvote me!

Comment: Seems to work fine? https://dotnetfiddle.net/sQKcfZ

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Certain operations are not allowed within [`foreach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> The **foreach** statement is used to iterate through the collection to get the information that you want, but ***can not be used to add or remove items*** from the source collection to avoid unpredictable side effects.

If you are trying to add or remove the dictionary elements within `foreach` you may get

> System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Comment: Who will add more? :D

Comment: How on earth did this get 8 upvotes within a minute when the answer was a comment?

Comment: Yes, this is an error I'm getting. Thanks for the help. Will mark correct when I get the ability to do so.