# Removing an object from a list and the game?

Tags: c#, list, xna, 2d-games

The problem I am having is that I have created a list with an object inside but when the player collides with the Object in question I can't remove it from the list.

```
//This is where the issue is
foreach (Objective seagull in seagulls)
{
    if (Objective.visable == false)
    {
        seagulls.Remove(seagull);
    }
}
```

EDIT: My problem now after changing to a for loop is that the remove does not work, I have no Idea what the remove function is asking me for ?

Comment: Please show your code and exception message as a text in question itself. People don't need to follow 3rd party sites to see your code.

Comment: I can't there will be too much code?

Comment: And try to simplify the code as much as possible to fastly get where you are stuck. With the current source-code it may take much time to understand what you´re doing and where the actual problem is. Furthermore when you click on details within the debugger when showing the sexception, what do you get there? Is there a stacktrace?

Comment: you cannot modify a collection while looping through it with a `foreach`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove elements from a generic list while iterating over it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582285/how-to-remove-elements-from-a-generic-list-while-iterating-over-it)

Comment: Don't use `foreach`, use `for` with an inverse indexer and removed the last.

Comment: See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604831/collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-may-not-execute

Comment: Could you explain inverse indexer please?

Comment: We don't need your entire application, just the relevant code. Pastebin is blocked at my work (and the job I had before this) so I can't look at your code. No reason to post the exception as a screenshot either. Loop through it backwards; `for (int i = myList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) myList[i].Remove` or whatever it would be

Comment: Sorry, First time using Stack. Didn't know what was needed. And Thanks for the help everyone

Comment: @Adam take a look at the help section, in particular this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: In the new `for` loop, you should [`RemoveAt`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I have used RemoveAt(i), But the object is still there.

Answer (score 2):

When using a `for`, you should use `RemoveAt` since it will reference your index.  `Remove` will expect a value to match, this is may be partially why your new `for` implementation doesn't work.

---

The reason you're receiving that error, is because you're enumerating through a collection that was modified.  If you utilize a `for` loop, instead of `foreach` you'll be able to iterate through while removing particular indexes.  Otherwise, you'll need to create a separate `List`, which is a copy of your `List`.  Remove it, then equal it to the other.

```
int total = example.Count;
List<Example> example;
for(int i = 0; i < total; i++)
     if(...)
     {
           example.RemoveAt(i);
     }
```

The conditional will be your check, before removing.  I'm not sure what that would be, but it would be similar to that.  I simplified code a bit for brevity sake.

Comment: Your example works, but just to clarify. If the object is removed from the list does that mean it stops excising therefor all the logic for that object stops working. Because allthough I am not getting any errors anymore the score continues to rise as if the object was there.

Comment: Here is the new code,  if (Player.playerBound.Intersects(Objective.objectiveBound))
            {
                Objective.visable = false;
                Player.score = Player.score + 10;
                for (int i = seagulls.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    if (Objective.visable == false)
                    {
                        seagulls.RemoveAt(i);
                    }
                }
                    
            }

Answer (score 0):

Yo can put some flag like 'active' in your 'seagull' and then remove all

```
seagulls.removeall(c => c.active == false)
```