# How to remove strings that contain at least an uppercase letter in them from an ArrayList<String>?

Tags: java

So, I have an **ArrayList** called **totalListOfWords**. It contains a mixed of words from which has both lower and upper case letters in it. I want to remove all the words that contain upper case letter in them. Below is what I have.

I have a helper method called **containsUpperCaseLetter**. It basically checks whether a string contain an upper case letter in it.

Then I loop through my **totalListOfWords** using for loop and check each word in the list whether it contains an upper case letter. If so, I try to remove it. But it only remove some words. May be I am choosing the wrong type? Help please.

```
public class TextProcessor() {
   ArrayList<String> totalListOfWords = new ArrayList<String>();
   
   totalListOfWords.add("The");
   totalListOfWords.add("Project");
   totalListOfWords.add("Gutenberg");
   totalListOfWords.add("eBook");
   totalListOfWords.add("of");
   totalListOfWords.add("Pride");
   totalListOfWords.add("and");
   totalListOfWords.add("Prejudice");
   totalListOfWords.add("by");
   totalListOfWords.add("Jane");
   totalListOfWords.add("Austen");

   public void processText() {
      for (int i = 0; i < totalListOfWords.size(); i++) {
         if(containsUpperCaseLetter(totalListOfWords.get(i))){
            totalListOfWords.remove(i);
         }
      }
      System.out.println(totalListOfWords);  
   }   

   public boolean containsUpperCaseLetter(String s){
      for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
          if(Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(i))){
              return true;
          }
      }
      return false;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      TextProcessor t1 = new TextProcessor();
      t1.processTextAtURL(url1);
   }
}
```

Comment: Step through your code with the debugger and look at which words actually get checked. Think about the effect of removing words on the indices of the other words.

Comment: Hi, I think this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36669154. It's for a different language, but explains the problem.

Comment: If you remove an item from the arrayList (The same one you are currently iterating), then the very next item replaces the current item, and will be missed entirely in your loop.

Comment: Be weary of blindly checking uppercase without setting locale so that your app doesn't break in some countries.  For example, in Turkey, a lowercase `I` may change to `ı` (notice the missing dot).

Comment: You don't need the **containsUpperCaseLetter()** method. You can do all this with one line: `totalListOfWords.removeIf(strg -> !strg.equals(strg.toLowerCase()));`. Now you just need to display what remains within the ArrayList.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I really do appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you remove the element at index `i`, the next element is now at `i` instead of `i+1`. You would have to decrement `i` so it checks the same index again:

```
for (int i = 0; i < totalListOfWords.size(); i++) {
    if(containsUpperCaseLetter(totalListOfWords.get(i))){
        totalListOfWords.remove(i);
        i--;
    }
}
```

Or you can use an iterator instead:

```
for (Iterator<String> iter = totalListOfWords.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
    if (containsUpperCaseLetter(iter.next())) {
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

Or you can skip the whole loop altogether:

```
totalListOfWords.removeIf(word -> containsUpperCaseLetter(word));
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir. Very helpful. I was literally stuck figuring this out for 2 days.

Comment: The debugger is your friend.

Comment: Alternatively, iterate over the list BACKWARDS so that when you remove something you don't need to fiddle with the `i` variable at all...