# Best way to iterate over a list and remove items from it?

Tags: c#, list, iteration

I need to iterate over a `List<myObject>` and remove items that answer a certain condition.

I saw this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1582317/5077434):

> Iterate your list in reverse with a for loop:
>
> ```
> for (int i = safePendingList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
> {
>     // some code
>     // safePendingList.RemoveAt(i);
> }
> ```
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> var list = new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, 10));
> for (int i = list.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
> {
>     if (list[i] > 5)
>       list.RemoveAt(i);
> }
> list.ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i));
> ```

But I understood that `for` is less efficient than `foreach`,

So I thought of using the later as follows:

```
foreach (var item in myList.ToList())
{
    // if certain condition applies:
    myList.Remove(item)
}
```

Is one method better than the other?

**EDIT:**

I don't want to use `RemoveAll(...)`, as there is a large amount of code inside the loop, prior to the condition.

Comment: "better" as in what? performance? memory? legibility?

Comment: `for` is not less  efficient than `foreach`. And instead of a loop, you can use `RemoveAll`, which has even better performance: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Jcl 1. Better performence
2. Better coding practice

Comment: You can't remove items from a the same list you're using in the foreach, you'll get an exception (System.InvalidOperationException).

Comment: For sequences that give you give you constant time index-based access to elements (e.g. lists, arrays), a standard `for` loop is guaranteed to be more efficient than a `foreach` simply because of the iterator protocol overhead of the latter… not that it matters much since the actual item removal (and the subsequent array reshifting) is the expensive part.

Comment: @Marco You missed the ToList in his code.

Comment: If there is a large amount of code in the loop then simply put it in a method and call it in the Predicate of RemoveAt.

Comment: There is no such thing as `RemoveAll()` in LINQ.

Comment: @poke That is CERTAINLY not true for arrays, for which `foreach` is highly optimised.

Comment: As Jcl's comment hinted at, this question is primarily opinion-based (Is X better than Y?") and is off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Willy-nilly you have to *loop* over the list, and the `for` loop is the most efficient one:

```
  for (int i = safePendingList.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i) 
    if (condition)
      safePendingList.RemoveAt(i);
```

If you want to remove in *range* (not in the *entire list*), just modify *for* loop:

```
  // No Enumarable.Range(1, 10) - put them into "for"
  for (int i = Math.Min(11, safePendingList.Count - 1); i >= 1; --i)
    if (condition)
      safePendingList.RemoveAt(i);
```

Or if you have to remove items in *forward looping*:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < safePendingList.Count;) // notice ++i abscence
    if (condition)
      safePendingList.RemoveAt(i);
    else
      i += 1; // ++i should be here
```

On the contrary `safePendingList.ToList()` creates a *copy* of initial `safePendingList` and this means *memory* and *CPU* *overhead*:

```
  // safePendingList.ToList() - CPU and Memory overhead (copying)
  foreach (var item in safePendingList.ToList()) {
    if (condition)
      myList.Remove(item); // Overhead: searching
  }
```

However, the most *reasonable* plan in many cases is just to *let .Net work* for you:

```
  safePendingList.RemoveAll(item => condition);
```

Comment: One thing to remember is that using `RemoveAt()` is much less efficient than `RemoveAll()` because it will keep shuffling up all elements at an index greater than the removed one.

Comment: `safePendingList.RemoveAll(item => condition);` is the closest to a higher-order `filter`y function

Comment: As well as being short and readable, `RemoveAll` has the major benefit that it takes linear time, regardless of how many or which items need to be removed. Solutions based on `RemoveAt` may take quadratic time due to needing to shift large sections of the list repeatedly.

Comment: you sucked my answer into yours :-\

Answer (score 9):

to remove items with a certain condition you can use

```
list.RemoveAll(item => item > 5);
```

instead of

```
var list = new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, 10));
for (int i = list.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (list[i] > 5)
        list.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `myList.Where(x => x > 5)` ?

Comment: @arrowd - to get the same result it must be `myList = myList.Where(x => x <= 5).ToList();`

Comment: I don't want to do it with LINQ, as the condition is complex and is built up as the loop progresses

Comment: @arrowd Making a new copy of a list omitting some items is not the same as removing items from an existing list.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Wouldn't `RemoveAt` traverse the list again?

Comment: @arrowd He's saying to use `RemoveAll()`, not `RemoveAt()`

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `foreach` cannot work with collection while it is being modified this will lead to `InvalidOperationException`.

Using `.ToList()` inside `foreach` allows us to avoid that but this copies the entire collection it result in looping through collection twice (first time when it copies all elements and second time to filter it).

The `for` loop is better option because we can go through collection once. Apart of that you can filter collection using `LINQ` `Where()` method, something among the lines of :

```
var myFilteredCollection = myList.Where(i => i <= 5).ToList();
```

If your conditions are complex you can move this logic to separate method :

```
private bool IsItemOk(myObject item)
{
   ... your complicated logic.
   return true;
}
```

And use it in your LINQ query :

```
var myFilteredCollection = myList.Where(i => IsItemOk(i)).ToList();
```

Other option is to do it vice-versa. Create new collection and add elements based on condition. Than you can use `foreach` loop :

```
var newList = new List<MyObject>(myList.Count);

foreach (var item in myList)
{
    // if certain condition does not apply:
    newList.Add(item);
}
```

P.S.

But as already mentioned `.RemoveAll()` is better because this way you do not have to 're-invent the wheel'

Answer (score 4):

Neither method shows significant differences. `for` and `RemoveAll` looks a bit faster (more likely because using `Remove` you are duplicating your list and it needs to recreate it... using value types, this also means doubling the needed memory). I made some profiling:

```
public static void MethodA()
{
    var list = new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, 10));
    for (int i = list.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (list[i] > 5)
            list.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}

public static void MethodB()
{
    var list = new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, 10));
    foreach (var item in list.ToList())
    {
        if (item > 5)
            list.Remove(item);
    }
}

public static void MethodC()
{
    var list = new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, 10));
    list.RemoveAll(x => x > 5);
}

public static void Measure(string meas, Action act)
{
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    var st = new Stopwatch();
    st.Start();
    for (var i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        act();
    st.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"{meas}: {st.Elapsed}");
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Measure("A", MethodA);
    Measure("B", MethodB);
    Measure("C", MethodC);
}
```

The result:

> A: 00:00:04.1179163
>
> B: 00:00:07.7417853
>
> C: 00:00:04.3525255

Other runs give even more similar results (note that this is for 10 million iterations on a 10 item list [thus doing 100 million operations]... a difference of ~3 seconds is not what I'd call "significant", but your mileage may vary)

So go with what you think you can read better (I'd personally use the `RemoveAll` method)

**Note**: as you grow your list (this is just 10 items), `MethodB` (the `foreach` one that duplicates the list) will be slower and the differences will be higher, since the duplication of the list will be more costly. For example, doing a list of 1,000 items (with the condition being on 500 instead of 5) and 100,000 iterations, makes `MethodB` be 34 seconds, while both others run under 2 seconds on my machine. So yes, definitely don't use `MethodB` :-)

**This doesn't mean that `foreach` is less efficient than `for`**, it only means that for using `foreach` to remove items from a list, you need to duplicate said  list, and that is costly.

This other method (using `foreach`) should be about as fast as the `for` or `RemoveAll` methods (it's a tiny bit slower in my profiling -because it allocates a new list, I figure-, but pretty much negligible):

```
public static void MethodD()
{
    var originalList = new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, 1000));
    var list = new List<int>(originalList.Count);
    foreach (var item in originalList)
    {
        if (item <= 500)
            list.Add(item);
    }
    list.Capacity = list.Count;
}
```

You just need to reverse the condition.

I'm not suggesting this method, just proving that `foreach` is not necessarily slower than `for`

Comment: Right, if you want to see which horse is faster… And often the best policy is to let .Net do its work - `RemoveAll`, +1

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I was expecting this result from theory, but yes, nothing like racing the horses :-)

Comment: I had no doubt you *had known*, but since there's "...But I understood that `for` is less efficient than `foreach`..." in the question, the best way to ensure that quite the *contrary* is true is to let horses run.

Comment: A 10 element list is far too small for this kind of test, because the overhead of memory allocation etc is going to distort the results. Try it with a list of a million elements (removing all items with an index less than 500,000)

Comment: @MatthewWatson yeah, i noted that in a update

Comment: Why are you adjusting `Capacity` in `MethodD` and not in any of the others?

Comment: @Johnbot because I've set the capacity explicitly higher in that method (on the list constructor), and haven't in the others. It's definitely not needed but since I know it'll more likely be higher (in my case, twice the needed one), I'd rather adjust it after I'm done

Comment: But in all the other methods you've still got a list with the initial capacity of at least `originalList.Count`.

Comment: @Johnbot yeah, I suppose you are right... I guess I should have adjusted in the others too, but frankly, `MethodD` is the only one that creates a list I actually not copied from the original question and wrote myself, so I didn't give it much thought to the others :-)

Comment: The difference in performance between `MethodA` and `MethodB` is most likely due to using `Remove` rather than `RemoveAt`.  `Remove` has to search the whole list for the item in question, while with `RemoveAt`, you're telling it exactly where to find it.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman you are totally spot on there

Answer (score 1):

Another way could be to foreach the list, set the item to null and then do a linq remove to (item => null), as already said, it's up to you to choose the way that suits you better