# How do I remove a list item in a foreach while its function is undetermined?

Tags: c#, list

I've got a List of objects which have a method that's being ran. Some objects' method remove other objects from the list, which causes an InvalidOperationException.

The code somewhat (simplified) looks like this:

```
static List<myObject> olist = new List<myObject>();
// fill list
foreach (myObject obj in olist) {
    obj.func();
}
```

A func() of an obj *may* contain something like this:

```
olist.Remove(specificListItem);
```

Which obviously causes the exception above. Right now, the current setup of having a foreach run the objects' own methods have to stay - what workaround would be the best here?

Since we're running a method of undetermined (at the time of beginning the foreach) function - inside of an object, we can't use tricks live reversing the order [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582285/how-to-remove-elements-from-a-generic-list-while-iterating-over-it).

Comment: How does the object know what list it's in?

Comment: It's a static list; fixed in question.

Comment: Both of those (static field and object knowing about its container) are code smells.  I would suggest redesigning your process to clean those up; if you aren't interested in that a `for` loop is the next best option.