# What is the disadvantages of using List<T>.RemoveAll like ForEach?

Tags: c#, list, foreach

On some code, I used the `List<T>.RemoveAll` as a special `List<T>.ForEach` which allow removing elements on the fly because I thought it would gives better performance: **O(n)** with one combined loop in `RemoveAll` vs **O(2n)** with one `ForEach` and one `RemoveAll`.

Example:

```
gameObjects.RemoveAll( object => {
    if (object.Active){
        // Doing stuffs on object
    }
    return !object.Active;
});
```

At least in my code, this hack worked as it does iterate in the right order and encountered no bug so far.

One disadvantage of this hack is code maintainability/readability as it's not this method original purpose and may cause confusion later.

So my question is: Is there other disadvantages of this hack (performance, possible bugs,...)?

Comment: Do you _need_ better performance here? Have you seen a performance problem in your code that justifies a "hack"?

Comment: What do you mean when you wrote O(2n)?

Comment: This isn't a, as you say, "hack"? Seen and used it in kind of this way with other things too

Comment: There can be many in-game objects in the list so performance can be a hit. Yeah, I haven't profiled it (not even done the coding), so I don't know if it's needed just thought maybe this hack can help.

Comment: If you rely on preserving order, don't use this. There's no such guarantee. Apart from that, it's a matter of style - somebody might not care, somebody might want to separate your limbs and your body. And forget about algorithmic complexity - you have no guarantees on that either, since the implementation of the `RemoveAll` method (or `ForEach` for that matter) is not part of the contract. In any case, you might be better served by defering removals after all the updates anyway - otherwise you'd get a lot of fun when objects depend on other objects, and you remove them in unspecified order.

Comment: @Arendax I don't think it is hack - I think it is indication whether one should even try to read the rest of the code or simply throw it away and start over.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Because ForEach and RemoveAll each take O(n) so both combine to O(2n) if we don't again generalize it to O(n). Sorry for my English.

Comment: If you're worried about readability, you should extract the "doing stuff" part into a method.

Comment: @Tr1et But O(2n) == O(n).

Comment: @Servy Well, maybe I'm just care too much about the performance.

Comment: Beside readability, there is no advantage or disadvantage. But RemoveAll is typically used only for removing and not for doing any logic. So that might confuse the person who will read it after you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing twice as much work in one iteration isn't actually twice as efficient as having two iterations, each doing half the work.

Which is faster, doing one lap around a mile long track, or doing two laps around a half mile long track?

You're unnecessarily complicating your code by trying to do all of this in one iteration, and you're not actually benefitting from it.  Just have one call to `RemoveAll` to remove all of the inactive items, and then `foreach` over the collection to act on the active items.

Comment: Unless iteration is expensive (e.g to create enumerator something long running occurs), then *tricks* like this might do. This is not a case with `List.RemoveAll()`.

Comment: Thanks, so it's is okay to put trivial things like log or counting inside the remove all, right?

Comment: @Tr1et It all comes down to whether the operation is conceptually a part of the removal operation.  Doing something like counting the number of items being removed seems like it'd qualify to me.  What you want to avoid is operations that have nothing to do with the removal being put in there, such as performing an operation on all of the active items.

Answer (score 0):

I am not buying into the premise that this is a hack, but a usage of design elements in a specific manner. For it seems to be doing its job as per the documentation *Removes all the elements that match the conditions defined by the specified predicate.* ([List.RemoveAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx) )

> ...worked as it does iterate in the right order and encountered no
>   bug so far.

There are two steps here, one to operate on each item and the second is to remove from the list. Using this method works and is readable. That fact that the determination of deletion has been predetermined is inconsequential.

Purists will complain, but the operation needs to loop through the items anyway, **why not centralize the job**.

> code maintainability/readability

For maintenance...just comment the intent to any future developer.

> Is there other disadvantages of this hack (performance, possible bugs,...)?

No, I would view a hack as having two loops when one could *logically* be done.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that the work being done is to compute whether or not the item is to be removed.  It's not.  The business logic is to remove all inactive items and to perform some work on all of the active items.  They are conceptually separate operations; the OP is asking about the merits of combining these separate business tasks into one method call for the sake of performance.   If the operation being performed was *to determine if the item should be removed* then that would be a completely different matter.

Comment: The fact that you feel that this transformation is sufficiently confusing that you feel it would need a comment in order to explain its actions to future readers is a *very* strong indication that it's *not* more readable/maintainable than separating the separate operations.  If you'd feel that combining them in this was was more readable, why would it merit such an explanation?

Answer (score -1):

I found this on Stackoverflow:
[Stackoverflow - Maybe same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582285/how-to-remove-elements-from-a-generic-list-while-iterating-over-it)
I guess your way works out, I see no problem, but as you said, might be hard to understand someday. I would prefer the "backloop"

This is the other way descibed in the **link** above: As commented by wise men, ist slower O(n*m) - worst case

```
var list = new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, 10));
for (int i = list.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (list[i] > 5)
    list.RemoveAt(i);
 }
list.ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i));
```

Comment: Removing `m` items from a list by calling `RemoveAt` `m` times is O(n * m), while calling `RemoveAll` is O(n), as it only needs to do one defrag of the list.

Comment: You're suggesting making the OP's code worse, both in terms of readability and very notably so in terms of performance, and complain when you get downvotes *for contributing harmful content*?   You think I should upvote a post that is suggesting a harmful change even though I know better?  I'm not that mean.  That someone else posted a bad solution to a problem doesn't mean it's not a bad solution to the problem (although also note that that answer does mention `RemoveAll`).  Finally, while you only *explicitly* iterate it once, `RemoveAt` must iterate the collection internally.

Comment: ... You realy downvote anything in not your oppinion. The question was if there is another way, which is more readable - if so this is the answer to it, als 400+ people think in posted thread above.

Comment: I even told above, that this is the same question - it's more or less a *duplicate*...

Comment: Hey guys. this conversation is pointless. Let's just move on.