# checking list of monsters error Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to destroy monster when walking on it but each time I destroy it then i got this error:

> InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1+Enumerator[UnityEngine.GameObject].VerifyState () (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/List.cs:778)
>
> TimeMap.MoveSelectedUnitTo (Int32 x, Int32 y) (at Assets/TimeMap.cs:148)

`foreach(GameObject thisMonster in monsterList) {
                    if(thisMonster.GetComponent<Monsters>().tileX == selectedUnit.GetComponent<Unit>().tileX && thisMonster.GetComponent<Monsters>().tileY == selectedUnit.GetComponent<Unit>().tileY) {
                        CarryMonster(thisMonster);
                        counter++;
                    }
                }`

I am still trying to figure out what is wrong with this. The list certainly is not empty. I put monsters there every 5 moves.

Comment: You can't remove items from a list that you are enumerating. This means that your CarryMonster is trying to remove the reference passed and this is not allowed

Comment: what kind of duplicate? Does it mean that I can use foreach only once?

Comment: No you can't delete items you are enumerating though with a foreach loop. Change it to a for loop.

Comment: Okay, I will try that. Thank you! Can you help me how to write thisMonster.GetComponent<Monsters>().tileX in for loop? I get to here: monsterList[i].tileX but I got error: error CS1061: Type `UnityEngine.GameObject' does not contain a definition for `tileX'

Comment: Don't forget to inverse the loop. If you don't you're going to mess up the index as you delete. Take a look at this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582285/how-to-remove-elements-from-a-generic-list-while-iterating-over-it

Comment: Use a normal for loop, depending on the type of the list. You can get the element at a given index with the indexer `[index]` method if it is a `List<E>`. You can also simply use the `ElementAt` extension method in `System.Linq`. Remember to use `monsterList[i].GetComponent<Monsters>().TileX`