# What's the best algorithm to remove items from a list that is reindexed when an item is removed?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm dealing with a probably common situation that I don't even know how to formulate in a search.

I decided to ask for guidance, not necessarily to get any piece of code but to ask about what is the best approach for this kind of situation.

I have a list named `arrIntIndexesOfJobsThatWillBeKilled` containing the original indexes of the items that must be removed from another 5 lists.

However, when I remove an item from the other 5 lists, they are reindexed, and the indexes I once had in `arrIntIndexesOfJobsThatWillBeKilled` are now invalid.

I want to remove only the items linked to the original indexes...

What is the best algorithm to handle this situation?

```
arrIntIndexesOfJobsThatWillBeKilled = arrIntIndexesOfJobsThatWillBeKilled.Distinct.ToList

If arrIntIndexesOfJobsThatWillBeKilled.Count > 0 Then

    For Each Job As Integer In arrIntIndexesOfJobsThatWillBeKilled

        arrStrJobDescription2.RemoveAt(Job)
        arrStrPNDirectories2.RemoveAt(Job)
        arrIntJobIDDirectories2.RemoveAt(Job)
        arrStrSubDirectories2.RemoveAt(Job)
        arrStrNCFile2.RemoveAt(Job)

    Next

End If
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove elements from a generic list while iterating over it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582285/how-to-remove-elements-from-a-generic-list-while-iterating-over-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the order of removal to reverse one - delete bigger indexes first. Not fluent with VB, but in C# it will look like:

```cs
arrIntIndexesOfJobsThatWillBeKilled = arrIntIndexesOfJobsThatWillBeKilled
    .OrderByDescending(i => i) // assuming list of integers here, or .OrderDescending() for later framework
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

And then proceed with deletion.

P.S.

`If arrIntIndexesOfJobsThatWillBeKilled.Count > 0 Then` check is redundant - `foreach` handles empty collections just fine.

Comment: The only change for VB.NET would be to replace `(i => i)` with `(Function(i) i)`.

Comment: Unfortunately the indexes are not ordered... So starting backwards won't solve this... I'll keep trying...

Comment: @DanielSantos what do you mean that they are not ordered? What stops you from ordering them? The code is provided in the answer.

Comment: My bad @GuruStron - I jumped to a conclusion before testing it. It works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After the guidance of the collaborators here, this is the code that works:

```vb
If arrIntIndexesOfJobsThatWillBeKilled.Count > 0 Then

arrIntIndexesOfJobsThatWillBeKilled = arrIntIndexesOfJobsThatWillBeKilled.OrderByDescending(Function(i) i).Distinct.ToList

   For Each Job As Integer In arrIntIndexesOfJobsThatWillBeKilled

       arrStrJobDescription2.RemoveAt(Job)
       arrStrPNDirectories2.RemoveAt(Job)
       arrIntJobIDDirectories2.RemoveAt(Job)
       arrStrSubDirectories2.RemoveAt(Job)
       arrStrNCFile2.RemoveAt(Job)

   Next

End If
```

Many thanks for once again educating this mediocre coder...