# foreach loop and changing the list/array (here in C#)

Tags: c#, list, foreach

one general question, I haven't found a clear-to-understand short answer on the net.

Is it not possible to use forach like that? :

```
foreach (element e in list)
{
  if (somecase)
    list.Remove(e)
}
```

This produces an exception.

Is foreach not so intelligent that it tracks 'live' the elements itself?

How can I solve this by writing smart good-looking code myself? Do I really have to return to (stupid :-) ) index counting ?

I ever thougth that mechanisms like  are intelligent and should help to write smart, easy-to-read code?

Thanks a lot,
F.

Comment: "mechanisms like" = "mechanisms like lists" ..... sorry

Comment: What happened when you tried?  (The exception is pretty clear.)  But seriously, you haven't found the [clear-to-understand answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582285/how-to-remove-elements-from-a-generic-list-while-iterating-over-it) yet?

Comment: By the way, you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78137697/edit) your post to make corrections.

Comment: `list.RemoveAll(somecase)` is also a thing.  _smart, easy-to-read code_